# Trouble streaming mp3 file in MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player

Try the URL in a browser below, it streams fine. Why is there an error on prepare? I'm using Android 2.2...

Also, I can download the file to the SDCARD and play it just fine this way...its just an synchronous process which is not an ideal user experience..

```
05-19 00:00:00.370: INFO/System.out(5932): http://www.amazon.com/gp/dmusic/media/log_action.mp3/ref=/181-3250961-7148012?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00137ZWAC&TYPE=DigitalMusicSampleStream&CustomerID=&URL=http%3A%2F%2Famazonm-149.vo.llnwd.net%2Fs%2Fd6%2F100331%2F100331225%2F203942149_S64.mp3%3Fmarketplace%3D1%26e%3D1305784802%26h%3Dab654b0e41c1b60d472f4f5d0f5384d5
05-19 00:00:00.380: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(5932): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-19 00:00:00.380: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(68): setDataSource('http://www.amazon.com/gp/dmusic/media/log_action.mp3/ref=/181-3250961-7148012?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00137ZWAC&TYPE=DigitalMusicSampleStream&CustomerID=&URL=http%3A%2F%2Famazonm-149.vo.llnwd.net%2Fs%2Fd6%2F100331%2F100331225%2F203942149_S64.mp3%3Fmarketplace%3D1%26e%3D1305784802%26h%3Dab654b0e41c1b60d472f4f5d0f5384d5
05-19 00:00:00.380: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(68): ')
05-19 00:00:00.380: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(68): connect to www.amazon.com:80/gp/dmusic/media/log_action.mp3/ref=/181-3250961-7148012?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00137ZWAC&TYPE=DigitalMusicSampleStream&CustomerID=&URL=http%3A%2F%2Famazonm-149.vo.llnwd.net%2Fs%2Fd6%2F100331%2F100331225%2F203942149_S64.mp3%3Fmarketplace%3D1%26e%3D1305784802%26h%3Dab654b0e41c1b60d472f4f5d0f5384d5
05-19 00:00:00.380: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(68):  @0
05-19 00:00:01.770: INFO/AwesomePlayer(68): mConnectingDataSource->connect() returned -2147483648
05-19 00:00:01.770: ERROR/MediaPlayer(5932): error (1, -2147483648)
05-19 00:00:01.780: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(5932): create failed:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following tutorial, It also work on same technique, download and play audio file.

http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/

Comment: Link to blog.pocketjourney.com in answer is dead.